# How to get the paragraph number from a Word Document in Word Add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to create a Word Add-in. Suppose I have the following paragraphs, but the paragraph numbers were created by the Numbering List of Word (i.e. paragraph numbers not typed by me) :

1. Orange
2. Apple

My goal is to extract "1. Orange" as a paragraph, but when I used the sample codes from the Script Lab, I can only get "Orange" as a paragraph, but not the paragraph no. "1." This applies to "2. Apple" as well. What can I do to be able to accomplish my goal? Thanks!

```
$("#get-paragraph").click(() => tryCatch(getParagraph));

async function getParagraph() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let paragraph = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs.getFirst();
    paragraph.load("text");

    await context.sync();
    console.log(paragraph.text);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the [Paragraph.listItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#listItem) property of the paragraph. This returns a ListItem object. Get the [ListItem.listString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.listitem?view=word-js-preview#listString) of the ListItem. This should be the number. Then concatenate the number with the paragraph's text.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Could you also add the appropriate `load` commands?  I'm having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: @newname Please start a new question in Stack Overflow, since this is not really the same question as Jacky-Miu had.